# Is there a way to show a class mixin props in vue-styleguidist?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins, react-styleguidist, vue-styleguidist

I'm working on a project using **vuejs2** and the **vue-class-component** package to make the class components and using **vue-styleguidist** for documentation.

For a certain scenario I had to create a Mixin and this is done via extending the component class (as explained in the **vue-class-component** documentation [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#using-mixins) ), but unfortunately seems that the methods and properties of the mixin are not shown in the autogenerated props/methods table of **vue-styleguidist** through the **vue-cli-plugin-styleguidist** package. Is there any way to do it?

I am using the following versions:

```
vue-cli-plugin-styleguidist: ^3.11.4
vue-class-component: ^6.0.0
vue: ^2.6.6
```

This is a code example of the same structure I use:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component, { mixins } from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
class MyMixin extends Vue {
   /*
    * Mixin prop documentation text
    */
   mixinValue:boolean = true;

   /*
    * Mixin method documentation text
    */
   mixinMethod():string {
    return this.mixinValue ? 'some string' : '';
   }
}

@Component
export class MyComp extends mixins(MyMixin) {
   /*
    * Component prop documentation text
    */
   componentValue:string = 'some value';

   /*
    * Component method documentation text
    */
   componentMethod(): string {
    return this.mixinMethod(); 
   }
}
```

This when documentation is generated it just returns shows in the table **componentValue** and **componentMethod** and doesn't show at all the mixin part.